# CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I have tried every single thing I have found on the internet and nothing is working. It is very simple, I have a Program.cs file in my IOS folder which contains the Main method. It used to be called EVERYTIME and then one day I get a compile error and can't get past it. My Program.cs file which contains the Main looks like this;

[image]

As you can see, very basic and simple. I did try changing things to internal and\or adding public etc. but the error did not go away.

[image]

You can see from my structure it is a normal structure and like I said was working for a long time, couple months. One of things I tried was a repair on VS 2022 which did not work. I even tried downloading and installing VS 2022 Preview, Version 17.8.0 Preview 5.0 and that is what I am currently using. I really am at a loss with this and could use some help.

I read a few things about pointing to the Program.cs file as your startup member, but on the version of VS I am using, I do not see that as an option. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the error is pointing to that Program.cs and not a different one?

Comment: No, I guess I am not, but IOS, MacCatalyst and Tizen are the only folders that contain a Program.cs file and thus a Main method, nothing else contains a Main method, is there another class that is supposed to contain a main method in a Maui solution?

Comment: The error message should tell you the file path.  I ask because there is another iOS folder shown in your screenshot which makes me think it may be looking in the wrong place

Comment: The error message just says CSC in the file path and the other IOS directory you see in there shows as deleted with nothing under it.

Comment: I tested your code, however, didn't meet the error, please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add to your post.